# What is causing wireless mouse reception issues?

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, interference

Recently, I bought a Microsoft wireless keyboard/mouse set.

When the receiver is plugged into the back of the case, the mouse frequently becomes laggy/choppy. The problem disappears when the receiver is plugged into either a USB extender cable or the front of the case.

At first, I figured this is due to the distance, but even if I leave the extender cable laying on the floor (further away than if it was plugged into the back of the case) the mouse and keyboard respond perfectly.

What could cause the mouse to behave this way when plugged into the back of the case?

Comment: End of life batteries?

Comment: brand new batteries.

Comment: What frequency does the wireless use? It should say somewhere either on the box or device itself.

Comment: Do you have all your metal slot covers in place? If not, electromagnetic interference could be leaking from your machine. Do you have a Wi-Fi card in your machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably when you plug into the back there is metal back there that is shielding the receiver so that the signal is weak.  This would be more likely with the mini type receivers that don't project out of the socket very far.

Answer (score 1):

Antennas are a highly complex subject and it can be very hard to know what's going on with a particular setup. I am far from an expert on radios, but from what I understand:

Antennas create EM fields that propagate outward. If you hold a piece of paper in front of your face while screaming, a far away listener won't hear you while a nearby listener can still hear through erratic and seemingly random paths the sound waves take.

Similarly, conductive materials inside the ["near field"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field) of an antenna can cause excessive distortion of this field thus altering the [radiation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern) and signal strength in the 'far' field. This can even happen if the conductive materials aren't between the transmit antenna and the receiver, sorta like holding a piece of paper behind your head and somehow not being able to scream as loud! This happens because antennas create an electromagnetic field all around them! And this near field is altered by conductive materials as well as the [ground plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_plane). This is why antennas in "free space" have different radiation patterns than the exact same antenna a couple feet off the ground!

Akin to [tug of war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tug_of_war) on rollerskates, antennas too need some 'mass' to exercise their equal and opposite electromagnetic force on. For unbalanced antennas like [monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopole_antenna), this would be our planet (hence those 'unbalanced' antennas NEED a ground to operate). [Dipole antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna) are balanced antennas and use the opposite symmetric half of itself as a 'counter weight'. Sorta like a symmetric and orchestrated tug of war with a solid rope.

For your USB dongle? The computer case is probably the ground, or the opposite side of a dipole, however you want to look at it. The antenna's lack of 'room to breathe', proximity to it's 'ground', proximity to a noise source (the computer) and an imperfect "ground" or "counter-poise" or "symmetric half of a dipole" are probably all reasons why there might be reception issues. A USB extension cable might fix any number of these issues, or make them worse. It all depends on your setup.

For more information on antennas, I recommend these sources:

- http://www.antenna-theory.com/
- [The Amateur Radio stackexchange](https://ham.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have issues with my Bluetooth wireless mouse with my apple wired aluminum keyboard.  If the machine that the mouse is connected to is on the left of the keyboard, and the mouse is on the right, the mouse appears laggy and jumpy on the screen.  If the computer and mouse are on the same side of the keyboard, I don't have an problems.  I have noticed the same issue with apple's magic trackpad....

Anyway the point is that it could be anything....  A cordless phone too close to the system, the RF receiver is too far from the mouse, you have a metal desk, you live under power lines, the microwave is near your computer, etc. etc...

I would try moving some things around to see if that clears it up....   Or, if the USB extension cable does not bother you, use that to bring the receiver closer to the mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this with a little antenna explainer on what you're seeing.  A non-directional antenna will broadcast and receive in the direction of its ground plane. This sounds weird....a non directional antenna being directional....but this is how it works.  A non-directional antenna means by design the antenna itself does not have a direction, otherwise described as more or less transmit/receive gain/power in one direction, by itself.  A wire/rod sticking straight up out of the ground is considered a non-directional antenna vertically oriented. (An antenna like a yagi with horizontal rods that are large on one end and small on the other, forming a triangle of sorts, is an example of a directional antenna.) Stand this vertical wire/rod antenna up in the center of a round metal plate instead, and it still radiates/receives in all directions equally.  Now move it to the edge of the plate, and it will put all of its gain in the direction of where the plate is pointing. Think of this like a CB antenna on a metal car.  An antenna on the back of the trunk will transmit/receive forward of the car, with the flat metal of the car as the ground plane. If placed on the front of the hood, it will transmit mostly to the rear.  In addition, the receiving antenna and transmitting antenna orientation need to match for maximum gain.  So if a vertical transmit antenna is being received by a horizonal receive antenna, the gain is nowhere near as good.
Since the antenna orientation is unknown in the mouse and USB plug, it's hard to match this up.  USB plugs on the front of a PC are horizontal, and might be vertical in the back.  This could move the antenna from a 100% orientation match to a total 100% mismatch.  Likewise, the entire metal box of the PC could be a ground plane. Basically, the location and orientation of the USB plug could make major changes in the operational plane of the antenna.
Try using your USB extender wire, and taping the USB plug onto the back of the PC, with the USB plug sticking up just above the PC top.  If you are to the left or to the right of the PC, tape the USB plug on the top opposite corner from where you are using the mouse.  This will make the metal of the top of the PC a ground plane pointing at your location for maximum gain. You can also try twisting or flipping the USB plug into different orientations to see if it affects the signal gain.
The problem is, the manufacturers should stop treating these wireless devices as if they are inches apart. This could all be a moot point if they put even the slightest larger antenna or transmit power into these devices.

Comment: walloftextishardtoread